# Cannot access Express server in Heroku

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I created an App using React in frontend with express server. It works fine in local, problem arises when it is deployed on Heroku. Below are my codes

**React:**

```
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/blog/myposts'{email:localStorage.getItem('useremail')})
   .then(response=>{
        this.setState({blogs:response.data});
    })
    .catch(function(err){
         console.log(err);
})
```

**Express:**

**Index.js:**

```
var express= require('express');
var app = express();
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
var cors=require('cors');
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var Blogrouter= require('./src/route/Blogrouter')
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));
}

mongoose.Promise=require('bluebird');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://****:****@ds257838.mlab.com:57838/blogtest')
    .then(()=> {
        console.log('database connected sucessfully');
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        console.log('App Starting error:', err.stack);
        process.exit(1);
    });

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use('/blog',Blogrouter);
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
var listener=app.listen(port,function(){
    console.log("Listening to port..."+listener.address().port);
});
```

**Blogrouter.js:**

```
Blogrouter.route('/myposts').post(function(req,res){
    Blog.find({email:req.body.email},function(err,postblog){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else
            res.json(postblog);
    });
});
```

**Heroku Log:**

```
Build succeeded
2018-03-13T11:58:24.970891+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `yarn server`
2018-03-13T11:58:27.680742+00:00 app[web.1]: yarn run v1.5.1
2018-03-13T11:58:27.812888+00:00 app[web.1]: $ node index.js
2018-03-13T11:58:28.525364+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening to port...59689
2018-03-13T11:58:28.689928+00:00 app[web.1]: database connected sucessfully
2018-03-13T11:58:28.644493+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-03-13T11:58:30.507630+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.67da7fa4.css.map" host=learnhosting.herokuapp.com request_id=ad77ccbf-0af8-42c7-829c-a552c68e2cbe fwd="157.50.235.225" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=19ms status=200 bytes=14894 protocol=https
2018-03-13T11:58:30.620808+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.bfee714b.js.map" host=learnhosting.herokuapp.com request_id=50f8d5ea-0b55-4edf-91a6-67a50b4e70b2 fwd="157.50.235.225" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=123ms status=200 bytes=5553317 protocol=https
2018-03-13T11:58:30.792514+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/service-worker.js" host=learnhosting.herokuapp.com request_id=e00c1b9f-820e-4bba-8f9e-36c58b5b9ac4 fwd="157.50.235.225" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=3681 protocol=https
2018-03-13T11:58:30.931604+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.bfee714b.js.map" host=learnhosting.herokuapp.com request_id=5d5d78fa-1878-479d-9841-9306afb7dd11 fwd="157.50.235.225" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=240 protocol=https
2018-03-13T11:58:30.925296+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.67da7fa4.css.map" host=learnhosting.herokuapp.com request_id=875d14e1-9368-440f-9658-ece6e8aeb18d fwd="157.50.235.225" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https
2018-03-13T11:58:31.730206+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/service-worker.js" host=learnhosting.herokuapp.com request_id=4a391817-e8ee-4c9f-a56b-2e3eae39cb00 fwd="157.50.235.225" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https
```

when I opened my app(https://learnhosting.herokuapp.com/myposts) it showed the below message in console

```
GET http://localhost:5000/blog/myposts 404 (Not Found)
Viewpost.js:31 Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at e.exports (https://learnhosting.herokuapp.com/static/js/main.bfee714b.js:1:173370)
    at e.exports (https://learnhosting.herokuapp.com/static/js/main.bfee714b.js:1:747283)
    at XMLHttpRequest.p.(anonymous function) (https://learnhosting.herokuapp.com/static/js/main.bfee714b.js:1:172370)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this URL "localhost...".

```js
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/blog/myposts'{email:localStorage.getItem('useremail')})
   .then(response=>{
        this.setState({blogs:response.data});
    })
    .catch(function(err){
         console.log(err);
})
```

Comment: To what..?? That is the answer I am searching for.

Comment: Thank you, changed "localhost:5000" to "learnhosting.herokuapp.com" pushed into heroku. But the browser console displaying same error as before. Don't know why.

Comment: Happy I could help. But after you change the URL, it's not possible to give the same message, Try cash cleaning in browser

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to POST to the same domain, you can omit the domain and port completely.  Just POST to /blog/myposts like this:

```
axios.post('/blog/myposts'{email:localStorage.getItem('useremail')})
   .then(response=>{
        this.setState({blogs:response.data});
    })
    .catch(function(err){
         console.log(err);
})
```

Comment: I just want to retrieve data from db, so I sent post request from react through axios.post. In browser console I got 404 error (i.e) localhost:5000/blog/mypost not found

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer. Assuming you are trying to POST to the same domain, you can omit the domain and port completely. Just POST to /blog/myposts

Comment: Thank you, changed "localhost:5000" to "learnhosting.herokuapp.com" pushed into heroku. But the browser console displaying same error as before(connection refused to localhost:5000). Don't know why.

Comment: You dont need to specifically say "learnhosting.herokuapp.com" .  A relative path should work like "/blog/myposts".

Comment: I went through your code at https://learnhosting.herokuapp.com/writeblog.  The code is still POSTing to http://localhost:5000/blog/publish.

Comment: App now working properly, failed to run build. Thanks a lot